# Is an epistemological realism-idealism (at the same perspective) possible?

Tags: epistemology, idealism, realism

Can an idea/action/creation/perspective be both realistic and idealistic at the same time? For example, when I think of a form, or a matter, can I think about/create it as real and ideal? I know a distinction between the two lines of thought are very often being pitted against each other, and that German Idealism took it to the next level when they used both concept as a combination to create one whole philosophy, but is it possible to not combine them as two sides of a coin, or two parts of a whole, but as one and the same?

Edit:

I would like to clarify, I do not mean a concept in which there are both realistic and idealistic forces playing the field at the same time, but in contrast to each other. I mean a concept I'm which the two forces are actually one (and not in an abstraction study, but ACTUALLY one). I do not know if that is possible, as in any philosophy I've seen those two are always, at least in some way, do contradict one another.

Comment: It seems like you were studying Fichte-Schelling, now is this Holderlin-Schelling? I got the idea that you started your study of philosophy through Schelling from your other post. Maybe I completely misunderstand your post here, is this still a part of your study of Schelling?  If so, Stanford Encl. of Phil. has an entry on Schelling.

Comment: @Gordon I am studying Schelling at the most, I didn't exactly start my study there, but I am focusing on German Idealism currently. I do not know Hölderlin. This isn't exactly part of my study of Schelling, as in, the question popped in my head while studying him, sure, but the question isn't about Schelling in any way (as I know [or at least I think I know] Schelling was using that dialectics between idealism and realism to create his philosophy, like Fichte, but he didn't put them as the same force at the same time. Well, except the Absolute I, but that isn't exactly what I mean).

Comment: I see. Well  I am not very knowledgeable about Schelling, but it appears that his period of Identity Philosophy was influenced by Holderlin.  You may be interested in this in regard to your question. Well Holderlin does make an interesting appearance on the stage of German Idealism. There is information about this at the Standford Encyclopedia of Philosophy website article on Schelling.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but it seems to me that any idealistic theory must say that the space-time phenomena we usually call  'real' are in fact ideal.  Then what is truly real will be whatever is not an idea but, rather, what comes before ideas. It seems to me that making 'idealistic and realistic forces... ACTUALLY one' is what idealism does. But I'm aware I might be misunderstanding the question.  . .

Comment: @Gordon thanks, I'll read about Hölderlin.

Comment: @PeterJ I admit my question is rather confusing (it is possible I myself do not understand exactly what I want), but what you're referring to, the realism-idealism combination, but means of synthetic of the two, is what I said is not what I'm looking for, because this synthetic acknowledge the two as two individual forces that are being combined into one - which isn't what I think of. In that sense, space-time are being constructed of individual ideal and real forces. I think of a force which is initially both idealistic and realistic. Again, only asking for the possibility..

Comment: Perhaps you could make more clear what you mean by 'realistic' and how you see this as distinct from 'idealistic'. I'm a little confused by this distinction.   .